# Remove line break before certain text

Tags: notepad++

I have a document with thousands of line similar to the text below:

Chill Wave\n
,Curator:Tsepo Sofute Location: South Africa

In every instance I would like to remove the line break before ",Curator" so I end up with:

Chill Wave,Curator: Tsepo Sofute Location: South Africa

I have thousands of instances of this that all have ",Curator" to key off of. What is the command for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This replace operation will do it, searching for a newline:

```
Find what: \n,Curator
Replace with: ,Curator
Search mode: Regular expression
. matches newline : Checked
```

If you also have a carriage return, the Find expression will be
`\r\n,Curator`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked!